# How do I notify the main form from a called filewatcher class on error?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.8, file-watcher

I have a form that I'm calling a class that creates a filewatcher and does varies other things when the filewatcher fires. If an error occurs during the the filewatcher changed event, I need to let the main form know there was an issue.

My filewatcher class:

```
  internal static class PpsTransactionFileWatcher
  {
    private static FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

    public static Suburban.Miscellaneous.Response StartPpsFileWatcher()
    {
      var response = new Suburban.Miscellaneous.Response();
      response.IsSuccess = true;
      response.Message = "Success";

      try
      {
        CreateTrnFileWatcher();
        ProcessTransactionFile();
        return response;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        LoggingWrapper.Log("StartPpsFileWatcher", ex.ToString(), ex);
        response.IsSuccess = false;
        response.Message = ex.Message;
        return response;
      }
    }

    private static void CreateTrnFileWatcher()
    {
      try
      {
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
          Path = GlobalSettings.PpsDirectory,
          NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
          Filter = GlobalSettings.PpsTransactionFile
        };

        _watcher.Changed += TrnWatcherChanged;
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        LoggingWrapper.Log("CreateTrnFileWatcher", ex.ToString(), ex);
        throw;
      }
    }


    private static void TrnWatcherChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
        _watcher.Changed -= TrnWatcherChanged;
        ProcessTransactionFile();
        _watcher.Changed += TrnWatcherChanged;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        LoggingWrapper.Log("TrnWatcherChanged", ex.ToString(), ex);
      }
    }
}
```

On my form, I'm calling it like this:

```
var transresponse = PpsTransactionFileWatcher.StartPpsFileWatcher();
```

How would I notify my form that there was an exception thrown from this class after it's started from the changed event?

Comment: Perhaps you can implement an `event` for your `PpsTransactionFileWatcher`, which your form can subscribe to.

Comment: @Ibrennan208 Thank you for the reply! Can you offer an example? I've not worked with that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an `EventHandler` would suit your needs here. Below is an example of an internal static class that has an `EventHandler` `ErrorLogged` defined.

You should be able to see how the event is subscribed to in the `Program.Main`.

For this particular console example, it loops in the background and may randomly generate errors based on a random number generator. It will relay the error number to any subscribers of the event.

The lines commented in all caps are the ones of particular relevance to your situation.

```
    class Program
    {
        internal static class ExampleEventManager
        {

            // the event handler here can send information to anything that subscribes to it
            // we make use of the empty delegate here to avoid any null errors when calling the event
            public static EventHandler<int> ErrorLogged = delegate { }; // THIS LINE DEFINES THE EVENT ITSELF WHICH WE WILL SUBSCRIBE TO           

            // a bool to control the loop for demonstration purposes
            private static bool ContinueRunning = true;

            // Starts the example
            public async static void Start()
            {


                Random rand = new Random();
                int errorCount = 0;

                // await a task here to make async
                await Task.Run(() => {

                    // run while our "continue running" flag is still true, and while we have encountered less than 10 errors
                    while (ContinueRunning)
                    {

                        // adds some delay to feel like "real time data and errors"
                        Task.Delay(100).Wait();

                        // randomly generate an error 10 in 100 chance (instead of 1 in 10, because we can show the slight differences in number generated for a more complete example)
                        int error = rand.Next(0, 100);
                        if (error > 89)
                        {
                            // notify the event which sends the information to any subscribers
                            ErrorLogged(null, error); // THIS LINE IS HOW YOU CALL THE EVENT FROM THE CLASS THAT THROWS THE ERROR

                            // increase the error count (for example)
                            errorCount++;
                        }


                        // we exit if too many errors
                        if (errorCount >= 10)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Too many errors encountered!");
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    
                    Console.WriteLine("Example Stopped. Press any key exit program.");
                });
            }

            // stops the example
            public static void Stop()
            {
                ContinueRunning = false;
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // subscribe to the event
            ExampleEventManager.ErrorLogged += ExampleEventManagerExceptionThrown; // THIS LINE IS HOW YOU SUBSCRIBE TO THE EVENT

            Console.WriteLine("Starting Example...");

            ExampleEventManager.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Example Started. Press any key to stop.");

            Console.ReadKey();

            ExampleEventManager.Stop();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // This is Program writing to the console here
        static void ExampleEventManagerExceptionThrown(object sender, int eventParameter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error detected: {eventParameter}");
        }
```

Comment: awesome example, tyvm!!!